# How can I have the search results page stay in place be remembered whilst navigating back and fourth to it using mysite.com/?search=words idea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the 'back' button or the 'refresh/reload' button in the browser my search/filtered results disappear even though the 'input box' stays OK and remembers the typed keyword. How can I have the results page stay with the keyword whilst navigating back and fourth to the page, or refreshing/reloading using mysite.com/?search=words idea?

JS

```
var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;
$(document).ready(function init() {
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

markInstance = new Mark(table);
input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});    


function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
  }



function resetContent() {
    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 
  });
}

function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
    exclude: ['.nonsearch']
  })
}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');                    $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings
}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +     text +                     '"</p>'); 
}



/* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
/* on form submit find the trigger */
if( $(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0     ){
    /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
});    

    /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */    



// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

CSS

```
.input-wrap  {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
  display: block;
}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}


.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}


.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}



#myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
background: orange;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
mark {
background: initial;
}    .style1  {
text-align: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div class="input-wrap">
<label>
Search 
<input id="myInput" type="text" required
   placeholder="Search Titles" />
</label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
<p id="noMatches"></p>
<p class="hints">
Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
</p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please some sample code x

Answer (score 0):

You could probably save the search values in the sessionStorage and apply them when you revisit the page.

```
const params = window.location.search;
sessionStorage.setItem('previous_search', params);
```

Next time you visit the page, check if the url params is empty, then get them from the sessionStorage.

Comment: Thanks and I do like the simple approach, but none of these don't work so far - damn!

Answer (score 0):

From how I'm reading what you're looking to do I've had success using the [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) method. It adds a history event in the user's browser so they can navigate back/forth as usual and can reach the pseudo event you add yourself. You then add a history listener so when you go back/forth/reload it can see that history point and use the data from it to trigger any function you wish.

Looking at your code, it doesn't look like you have a submit button for your input, but you can fire the pushState event from any regular JS event. I'll just add some example code so you can see one possibility.

Example:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
  text = '';

// Keyup listener on input field
$(input).on('keyup', function(e) {
  text = input.value;

  // Add the text change to the browser history so users can go back/forward, and save url parameter in the history state
  let historyState = {
    'text': text,
  }
  window.history.pushState(historyState, null, `?search=${text}`);
});


// Run something after History listener finds search text exists
const updateSearch = function(text) {
  console.log(`I found the search to be: ${text}`);
}

// History listener
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
  let state = e.originalEvent.state

  if (state !== null) { //If text exists
    updateSearch(state.text)
  } else { //If no text set (URL has no params)
    console.log('no history state found')
  }
});
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

#noMatches:empty,
#noMatches:empty+.hints {
  display: none;
}

.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}

.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}

#myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

mark {
  background: initial;
}

.style1 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
Search 
<input id="myInput" type="text" required
   placeholder="Search Titles" />
</label>
</div>

<div class="hintsWrap">
  <p id="noMatches"></p>
  <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
  </p>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date1</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Type</th>
          <td>type2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Title</th>
          <td>title2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Description</th>
          <td>description2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Date</th>
          <td>date2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Type</th>
          <td>type3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Title</th>
          <td>title3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Description</th>
          <td>description3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="style1">Date</th>
          <td>date3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Experiencing issues with this snippet @couchwood

Comment: My snippet is more of an example of how I would use the history.pushState() method to log input history and be able to go back/forward in the browser. What are you getting stuck on implementing the method in your own code?

Comment: Even just implementing your first line of code stops the filtered page from displaying anything, wouldn't care only historySession is the way Id like to go. can it be simpler @couchwood

Comment: Can you help further?

Comment: "Even just implementing your first line of code stops the filtered page from displaying anything" - does this refer to the variable declarations? If so, you may be using a version of JS that can't use let, so you will need to use vars instead.

Outside of that, I'd take a look at the examples on the API pages to see a simpler example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API

Comment: OK @couchwood - could you do me a favor (Please) and write your code into mine - see if you have any success. It would be quite interesting to see

Comment: I updated the snippet to include your HTML and CSS, but I don't know how you'll actually use this so that's the best I can do. I did see the input wasn't working in my original snippet because it was not a jQuery object for the `.on()` event. At this point, I recommend you take a look at the examples on the web history API pages for more assistance